# before check user validation to check reCaptcha - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to check the Captcha [Google reCaptcha](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php?hl=es) in a handler before validate the user and password.

```
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "your_private_key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
     // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
     die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
     // Your code here to handle a successful verification
}
```

I'm using FOSUserBundle and I want to check if captcha is correct before the validation with a handler or extending some controller.

My question is, what handler can I use to do this? Something as beforeLogin?

Comment: Just want to let you know that there is a bundle for this. I am using `GregwarCaptchaBundle`available [here](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle) that you can literally install in 2 minutes.

Comment: Thanks @Patt! I installed yet and it's true, it's very easy to install, but at this moment I prefer reCaptcha from Google. Do you know if exists something as beforeLoginHandler or event or listener?

Answer (score 4):

I see this is an old question, but here is what I did, in case it helps someone.

You want to create a custom AuthenticationListener:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener;

class FormAuthenticationListener extends UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
{
    protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        // check for a valid captcha here
        // I am using the GregwarCaptchaBundle
        // only shown when throttling in my case
        $captcha = $request->request->get('login[captcha]', null, true);
        if (null !== $captcha) {
            $check = $request->getSession()->get('gcb_captcha');
            if ($captcha !== $check['phrase']) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('Captcha is invalid');
            }
        }

        return parent::attemptAuthentication($request);
    }
}
```

You would need to register your authentication listener in your Bundle config or the app config.

Example in YAML:

```
parameters:
    security.authentication.listener.form.class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\FormAuthenticationListener
```

Since you override the UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener, do not forget to end the method with `return parent::attemptAuthentication($request)` after your custom logic

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite FOSUserBundle login controller and insert captcha logic inside `loginAction`

Here you can find how to overwrite the controllers:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

Comment: Thanks @Ferhad. The problem is that loginAction from FOSUserBundle executes after login validation. I need before login validation.